# Mobile page being cut off at the top

Tags: css

I created and hosted a Jekyll website on github-pages using the HTML5 UP Alpha Theme found on "html5up.net/alpha"

For some reason, pages are being cut off at the top on mobile only. I've gone through the mobile css but I have been unable to locate any issues.

The site mobile css can be viewed here:

> http://pastebin.com/jwNwpXyF

And a screenshot of the problem can be seen here:

> http://imgur.com/ZPycfNH

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data crucial for the understanding of your question. Please post all relevant code, images and resources **in the question itself**, if the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning!

Comment: If your question has been answered, try to up vote the answer and accept it to appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background image of banner is getting smaller for mob device to maintain the ratio, because of which the `#main` is cutting from top as it has `margin-top:-26em` for desktop, the same applies on mob too.

To fix it you have to change the margin for mob devices. Try below css.

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  body #main {
    margin-top: -8em;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and contributing to Stack Overflow, however please take a second look at the question, for it seems to be off-topic according to the [help/on-topic]. Answering off-topic question make it look like it's okay to ask such questions - it's not. Off-topic questions might get closed and then deleted, which would nullify your contribution!

Comment: This was exactly the issue, thanks very much!